# PHP convert stdClass Object to string and reduce array with max value

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I want to convert a `stdClass` object to string and reduce an array with the max value from the `stdClass` object.

This is my array:

```
Array
(

[135] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 145
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 138
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 139
            )

    )

[140] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 163
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 155
            )
)
```

Basically it should look like this:

```
 Array
 (
 [135] => 139
 [140] => 164
 )
```

Is this possible? I've tried various foreach loops but i don't get it with the stdClass object...

My try so far:

```
 foreach($ids as $k => $v) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($v); $i++) {
        $idss[$i] = array()$v;
    }
 }
```

That doesn't work.

Comment: You got a sort of multidimensional array and you want a normal array? I don't see the "logic" behind the conversion. Please elaborate. One easy way to get rid of "objects" is to encode it using `json_encode()` and then decode it back with the second parameter set to `true`: `$output = json_decode(json_encode($input), true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will solve your purpose. let me know if anything goes wrong.

```
$ids[135][0]->ID = 145;
$ids[135][1]->ID = 135;
$ids[135][2]->ID = 155;
$ids[140][0]->ID = 125;
$ids[140][1]->ID = 135;
$idss = array();
foreach($ids as $k => $v) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($v); $i++) {
        if(!@$idss[$k] || $v[$i]->ID > $idss[$k])
        {
            $idss[$k] = $v[$i]->ID;
        }
    }
 }
 echo "<Pre>";
 print_r($idss);
 die;
```

Comment: `@` ? use `isset($idss[$k])`.

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much! If you have time could you explane what you did in the if clause? :)

Comment: Welcome.And sure! $k has 135 value for first iteration. so i checked for $idss[$k] exists or not if it exists then condition will be false and it checks for second condition. which is $v[$i]->ID > $idss[$k] means it checks that new value in iteration is larger than existing value in $idss array then it replaces it with new value. I hope you understands. thats what i can do in text message :)

Answer (score 1):

Already answered but here is a shorter version of this

```
$final_array =array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  $max = max(array_keys($val));
  $final_array[$key] = $val[$max]->ID ;
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Here `$arr` is your input array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some compariosn in your inner for loop to know which one holds the max value. Here is an example :

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($elements as $index => $value){
  $max = -1;
  $foreach($value as $obj){
    if($obj->id > $max)
      $max = $obj->id;
  }
  $new_arr [$index] = $max;
}
```